# How use local in Bash in conjunction with set -o errexit?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I'm new to Bash and I had a hard time to figure out why when I was using set -o errexit and a command fail, the script was not exiting.

It seems because I declared a local variable!

Please tell me how I can use local variable and set -o errexit at the same time.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

function test {
 local output=$(ls --badoption)
 echo "error code is $?"
 echo "output=$output"
}

test
```

Result:

```
./test.sh
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
error code is 0
output=
```

But:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

function test {
 output=$(ls --badoption)
 echo "error code is $?"
 echo "output=$output"
}

test
```

Result:

```
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think it's because `-o errexit` only applies if a command is a simple command (as defined in the bash manual page), while running the command while declaring a local variable isn't running it as a simple command.

Comment: It's kind of very important -o errexit. It sound like if I write good code with local I'm losing the functionality. Hopefully, the community will find a workaround. Also local have not much to do with the command itself, it's just a variable scope.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't arguing *for* the behavior, just noting what the behavior *is*. However, there's a simple workaround, which I put in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `set -o errexit` (or running bash with `-e`) only affects *simple commands* (as defined in the bash man page). `cmd` in `local output=$(cmd)` isn't considered a simple command, so `-e` doesn't have any affect (and `$?` doesn't have any relation to how `cmd` exited). A simple workaround is to split the line by replacing:

```
local output=$(ls --badoption)
```

with:

```
local output

output=$(ls --badoption)
```

In my testing that does everything you want, it will exit immediately, and if you replace the `ls --badoption` with just `ls`, it works, and setting `output` before calling `test` then echoing it afterwords shows `output` really is local to `test`.

Comment: Great, it's working. Wondering why my question have a negative vote. I provided executable code, I think the question have never been answered, and the code should have work if the designer of Bash was testing...

Comment: It's quite intentional that the exit status of the command substitution is lost. What do you think the exit status of something like `local x=$(exit 2) y=$(exit 3) z=$(exit 4)` should be, if not the exit status of `local` itself?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [`local`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) says:

> The return status is zero unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable.

So the return status of the `local` command is not affected by whether the command executed in the command substitution succeeded.

As blm indicated in his answer, you can get the effect you want by separating the declaration and assignment of the local variable. The return status of an ordinary assignment that uses command substitution is the return status of the subshell that executes the command.